# exclude data having specific value [substring within a string] using pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I have a column "Number field" (Excel sheet).   It has value as shown below.

```
Test_Number Number_field
1            0011 10 00A34 PS
2            0011 10 00A34 PS
3            0010 01 00A30 PS
4            0010 01 00A30 PS
5            0010 01 00A35 PS
6            0010 01 00A35 PS
```

Now, from these i need to remove those which contains `"0A34"` and `"0A35"`. How can i achieve this? I tried "filter" option, but I cannot search substring in a string using this. Please help

Comment: Please always try to select the correct answer in all your questions if somebody has provided a correct answer. And always encourage them by upvoting if they have helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this in two steps as follows.

 [image]

In `Filter rows` step you add the following conditions.
[image]

Comment: Thats new for me. Nice. :)

Comment: @mzy And I have never tried the step you have explained `User Defined Java Expression` Learned a new thing from your answer too :) Since it has more steps I thought to post this.

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of `User Defined Java Expression` step with following parameters:

- **Java expression:** `(Number_field.indexOf("0A34") != -1 || Number_field.indexOf("0A35") != -1) ? "Remove" : "Ok"`
- **Value type:** String
- **New field:** is_row_to_remove

and `Filter rows` step with this parameters:

- **The condition:** `is_row_to_remove = Remove (String)
- **Send 'true' data to step:** *Your next step*
- **Send 'false' data to step:** `Dummy (do nothing)` step

Flow explanation:

1. **User Defined Java Expression:** Java code finds `0A34` or `0A35` and marks such a row with `Remove` value in a new field `is_row_to_remove`
2. **Filter rows:** The step filters record stream according to value in `is_row_to_remove`. If value is set to `Remove` then continues with `Dummy` step. Otherwise continues to *your next* step.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do that in excel itself then you can use below formula and have filter on that to remove the records from your excel.
Add below formula and drag it upto your all records. Create filter on this new formula column and then remove the records.

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR( SEARCH("A34",B2), 0),IFERROR( SEARCH("A35",B2), 0)), "REMOVE", "KEEP")
```

check snap below.

[image: Excel Search Formula]

Hope this will help you.

If it helps then mark it as answer.